# How to add GooglePlayServices and BaseGameUtils libs to Android Studio 4.4

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

I know that there is many tutorials..., but for Eclipse(I don't know why Google can't provide tutorial for their own tool)...
    Let's start from the beginning, I want to add score board and achievements to my game. I'm using Android Studio 4.4. My project structure looks like:

```
    NameProject
    -> gradle
    -> Name
    ---> build
    ---> libs
    ---> src
    ---> build.gradle
    -> build.gradle //empty
    -> settings.gradle
```

I pasted: **google-play-services.jar** from

Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs

to *libs* folder(then right click -> add as library)

After that I downloaded [samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) and pasted BaseGameUtils directory to libraries directory. 
    My project tree looks like:

```
    NameProject
    -> gradle
    -> libraries
    ---> BaseGameUtils
    -> Name
    ---> build
    ---> libs
    ---> src
    ---> build.gradle
    -> build.gradle //empty
    -> settings.gradle
```

I extended MainActivity class (BaseGameActivity) and imported:

1. import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
2. import com.google.example.games.tq.R;

But Android Studio still can't see those libs...

My *build.gradle* looks like:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
        compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '18.1.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 16
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32+'
    }
```

My *settings.gradle* file:

```
    include '(:libraries):BaseGameUtils', ':Name'
```

Can you explain me step by step, how to add those libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for link, but it doesn't resolve my problem, there is nothing about BaseGameUtils lib...

Comment: There is no such version called Android Studio "4.4" till now. Please correct the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## I solve this problem by doing the next:

1. Importing BaseGameUtils directory (that that is inside the BasicSamples/libraries/) as a module on android studio.
2. Then adding this: **compile project(':BaseGameUtils')** inside the dependences to my build.gradle that is inside the app directory.
3. Import BaseGameUtils (alt+enter from the line where you find BaseGameUtils on your code)

Obs: I tried it by chance and worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

- From Sdk Manager update Google Repository and Google Play Services
- Download BaseSamples from GitHub
  https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples
- Create a new folder named "libraries" under your project root and copy BaseGameUtils under the libraries folder from your BaseSamples source you downloaded from GitHub
- add `':libraries:BaseGameUtils'` to your gradle settings file
- add `compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')` to your gradle file

Note: If you are following the tutorial from google developers be careful, BaseGameUtils.ResolveConnectionFailure and BaseGameUtils.ShowActivityResultError methods are changed.

Its the best solution to use

I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to copy google-play-services.jar to your libs directory if you are using gradle.
Gradle will add required files to your project (for google play services, it will be copied to `[project root directory]\build\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\[GMS version]`).
Try to modify the settings.gradle to:

```
include ':BaseGameUtils', ':Name'
```

And build.gradle to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar')
}
```